# C# XCeed creating PropertyGrid dynamically by code

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, xceed

I'm trying to create the `PropertyGrid` dynamically in code. So far, I can create and customize a   `PropertyGrid` inside the XAML credits to: [XCeed PropertyGrid customizing IntegerUpDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443733/xceed-propertygrid-customizing-integerupdown)
:
MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()    
        {   
        InitializeComponent();

        Sample or = new Sample();
        pg.SelectedObject = or;
        pg.ShowAdvancedOptions = true;
        EditorDefinition ed = new EditorDefinition();
        PropertyDefinition pd = new PropertyDefinition();
        pd.Name = "Value";
        ed.PropertyDefinitions.Add(pd);
        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();

        FrameworkElementFactory fac = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(PropertyGridEditorIntegerUpDown));
        dt.VisualTree = fac;

        DependencyProperty dp = PropertyGridEditorIntegerUpDown.DefaultValueProperty;


        fac.SetValue(dp, 10);

        ed.EditorTemplate = dt;
        pg.EditorDefinitions.Add(ed);
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid" x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="pg">
<xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions >

                      <xctk:EditorDefinition >

                           <xctk:EditorDefinition.PropertiesDefinitions >

                                < xctk:PropertyDefinition Name = "Value" />

                             </xctk:EditorDefinition.PropertiesDefinitions >

                              <xctk:EditorDefinition.EditorTemplate >

                                   <DataTemplate >

                                       <xctk:PropertyGridEditorIntegerUpDown Increment = "10" Value = "{Binding Value}" Maximum = "40" MinHeight = "0" Minimum = "-30" />

                                            </DataTemplate >

                                        </xctk:EditorDefinition.EditorTemplate >

                                     </xctk:EditorDefinition >

                                  </xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions >
    </xctk:PropertyGrid >  
</Window>
```

and the Sample class:

```
public class Sample
    {
        private int _Value;

        #region Public Properties

        [Category("Sample")]
        [DisplayName("Sample Value")]
        [DefaultValue(3)]
        public int Value { set; get; }

       #endregion

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the equivalent code:

```
EditorDefinition ed = new EditorDefinition();
PropertyDefinition pd = new PropertyDefinition();
pd.Name = "Value";
ed.PropertiesDefinitions.Add(pd);

FrameworkElementFactory fac = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(PropertyGridEditorIntegerUpDown));
fac.SetBinding(PropertyGridEditorIntegerUpDown.ValueProperty, new Binding("Value"));
fac.SetValue(PropertyGridEditorIntegerUpDown.IncrementProperty, 10);

DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = fac };
dt.Seal();
ed.EditorTemplate = dt;
pg.EditorDefinitions.Add(ed);
```

Comment: Thanks yet again :) I have another question now, I did the same thing for a `PropertyGridEditorComboBox` and now I can't add elements to this combobox. How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, you have been of great help, you have no idea :)